# Can I have only one Xamarin Content Page with no full screen in Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have seted `android:windowFullscreen = false` for achiving to fix an issue that was kicking out from screen some element views when soft keyboard is open. I was able to solve the problem, but now my whole app has no full screen mode. Is there any chance of having only a specific page without full screen mode in Xamarin Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin.Android you can add or remove full screen flag in Activity.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   .....
   //Add full screen flag
   Window.SetFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);

   //Remove full screen flag
   Window.ClearFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
}
```

Looks you are using a common theme that is applicable to all activities. So, all activities are following same. So, this can be reset in code behind or you can use two different theme one for full screen and other for without full screen.